# accessing picture box on childform, c#

Tags: c#

hi
i have childform and parent form
I want to show picture in picturebox in childform at run time.
How can I access it from parent form.
e.g.
i can change nackground of childform from parentform

it works           `childForm.BackgroundImage = Image.FromFile(str[2]);`
but how can i access picturebox.
i tried like this

```
    public PictureBox picturebox1
    {
        get
        {
            return picturebox1;
        }
        set
        {
            picturebox1 = value;
        }
    }
```

and then from parentform
 `childForm.picturebox1.Image = Image.FromFile(str[2]);`
but got  error.

An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' occurred in Unknown Module.
anyhint
regards,

Comment: Can you post the code you are using in context and the **exact** exception being raised.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This generates a StackOverflowException.  Your property getter is returning itself and the property setter is assigning itself.  Give it a different name.  Furthermore, you want to assign the *image*, not the control.  Fix:

```
public Image Image
{
    get { return pictureBox1.Image; }
    set { 
        if (pictureBox1.Image != null) pictureBox1.Image.Dispose();
        pictureBox1.Image = value; 
    }
}
```

Next time you ask a question like this, be sure to document the kind of error you see.  Exceptions are meant to help you.  Or to help us help you.